# create a json from pandas dataframe AND post to rest api

Tags: json, dataframe, api, dictionary

I need to send data to rest API which accepts this format

```
{'myattributes': 
 [{'a': {},
   'v': {},
   'c': {},
   'd': {},
   'e': {},
   'f': {},
   'g': {},
   'h': {}}]}
```

I am reading a file from a dataframe, how do i map dataframe to desired json format?

```
url = 'https://cyz.com/hello
response = requests.post(url, json=s, headers=head)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Are you looking for this?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 1):

````
import pandas as pd

# grabbing a sample file to demonstrate
df = pd.read_csv("https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/samples/PRECIP_HLY_sample_csv.csv") 

print(df)  # what it looks on read

# if the column names don’t match what’s needed for the api post json,rename them
df = df.rename(columns={'STATION':'a','STATION_NAME':'b',
                        'ELEVATION':'c','LATITUDE':'d',
                        'LONGITUDE':'e','DATE':'f','HPCP':'g',
                        'Measurement Flag':'h','Quality Flag':'i'})

print(df)  # what it looks like after the rename

# render a list of 'json' posts from the dataframe
posts = json.loads('{"items":' + df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso') + '}')

print(posts['items']) # see the results

# since posts['items'] is a list, the set of posts can be executed using list comprehension like line below
# [requests.post('http://someurl.com/path', json=post, headers={'Accept':'application/json'}) for post in posts['items'] ```
````